# Modulus of $e^z-3$?

Tags: complex-analysis, exponential-function

We define $f(z)=e^z-3$ for all complex numbers $z$.

I am trying to represent the modulus $|e^z-3|$  in terms of the real part of $e^z-3$?  Then maybe I can tell whether $|f^n(z)|\to\infty$ if and only if the real part of $f^n(z)$ goes to infinity.  Is that true? The $f^n$ means the function $f$ composed with itself $n$ times.

Comment: Hint: by the triangle inequality, $|e^z-3| \le |e^z| + 3$.

Comment: ... and $|e^z| = e^{\mathrm{Re}\,z}$

Comment: Ok, we get $|f(z)|\leq e^{Re(z)}+3$.  I'm not sure this helps answer my second question...